# Understanding why multithreading could not read a global variable

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, win32-process

With this global variable defined in the script upper focus

> t0 = time.time()   ## is global

and this function

> def timestamp(t0):
>   ... return ("[" + str(time.time()-t0)+ "] ") ## time stamping from initial start

I'm trying to timestamp every print() of my script with

> print(timestamp(t0) + ""...whatever..."")

This works, but when i'm enterring multithreading by

> for thread_id in range(win32-safe_os):
>         ... p = Process(target=fonction, args=((thread_id),"test"))
>         ... p.start()
>         ... thread_list.append(p)

in order to

> def fonction(thread_id,filetodo):
>      ... print(timestamp(t0)+"Load core "+str(thread_id))
>      ... print(timestamp(t0)+str(filetodo)+" on core "+str(thread_id))
>      ... print(timestamp(t0)+"Free core "+str(thread_id))

i get this stdout :

[2.70299983025] 297 jpg / 36087 files 
[2.75] Enterring multithreading
 [2.75] Win32 finds : 2 core(s) 
[0.0] Load core 0 
[0.0] test on core 0 
[0.0] Free core 0 
[0.0] Load core 1 
[0.0] test on core 1 
[0.0] Free core 1

I can see that my call to timestamp() and t0 is working, but not in p.start(). I'm wondering how(, and why) i need to correct ?

PS : I tried with time.clock, but in win32 it refers to the beginning of a THREAD (not a script)/

Comment: Just want to point out you're creating a new process, not a new thread.

Comment: You should use code blocks rather than blockquotes for your code. Indent each block of code with 4 spaces. Or select the block and press CTRL+K.

Comment: Threads (of the same process) run in a shared memory space, while processes run in separate memory spaces. <- OK, I see ... THX GREG !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each process has a separate instance of the global variable. If you want each process to see the same value, you'll need to pass that value as an argument to each process.

Comment: Each process has a separate instance of the global variable. <- I do not understand the "global" of the variable, so. THX.

Comment: Yes ! Absolutely correct. The answer was in the question, in fact with "def timestamp(t0):" ... You rocks David !

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

t0 = time.time() ## is global

def timestamp(t0):
    return ("[" + str(time.time()-t0)+ "] ") ## time stamping from initial start

def fonction(thread_id, filetodo):
    print(timestamp(t0)+"Load core "+str(thread_id))
    print(timestamp(t0)+str(filetodo)+" on core "+str(thread_id))
    print(timestamp(t0)+"Free core "+str(thread_id))

thread_list = []
for thread_id in range(2):
    p = Process(target=fonction, args=((thread_id),"test"))
    p.start()
    thread_list.append(p)
```

...outputs on my Linux machine:

```
[0.00588583946228] Load core 0
[0.00625395774841] test on core 0
[0.00644302368164] Free core 0
[0.007572889328] Load core 1
[0.00768899917603] test on core 1
[0.00770998001099] Free core 1
```

So this would be ok. Could you please send more complete code snippet?

Comment: On my Linux too; I'm working on win32 process. I'll try David Hefferman's solution. THX